# Hidden style visiblity on card flipping game JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `card flipping game` in `html, css, and js` and my last step is to have my cards hidden after the user guesses the right pair. At the moment, after matching the cards, the user is still able to see them. After looking at `w3schools`, I found a css style called `hidden` but I would like to implement it in my `js`. I am having trouble with this and any help would be appreciated. Below is the code snippet.

```js
function myclick() {
  var myLink = document.getElementById("mylink");
  myLink.onclick = function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "script.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    return false;
  };
  document.getElementById("mylink").click();
}




function clock() {
  var h1 = document.getElementById("clock"),
    seconds = 0,
    minutes = 0,
    hours = 0,
    t;

  function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
      seconds = 0;
      minutes++;
      if (minutes >= 60) {
        minutes = 0;
        hours++;
      }
    }

    h1.textContent =
      "Timer:" +
      (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") +
      ":" +
      (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
  }

  function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
  }

  timer();
}

var options = document.getElementById("options");
var userInput = options.options[options.selectedIndex].value;

var cover = [
  "bg.png",
  "bg.png",
  "bg.png",
  "bg.png",
  "bg.png",
  "bg.png",
  "bg.png",
  "bg.png"
];
var dragon_ball = [
  //   "ultra_instinct_golu.png",
  //   "ultra_instinct_golu.png",
  //   "vegeta.jpg",
  //   "vegeta.jpg",
  "picolo.jpg",
  "picolo.jpg",
  "krillin.png",
  "krillin.png",
  "gohan.jpg",
  "gohan.jpg",
  "cell.gif",
  "cell.gif"
];
var dragonball_cell = [];
var dragonball_ids = [];
var dragonball_ret = [];
var flipped = 0;
shuffle(dragon_ball);

function startGame() {
  //Start the clock timer
  clock();

  var out = "<table>";
  out += "<tr>";
  var i;

  //Create a table based on number of cards
  for (i = 0; i < cover.length; i++) {
    out +=
      '<td><div id="tile' +
      i +
      '" onclick="memory(this,\'' +
      dragon_ball[i] +
      "')\">";
    out += "<img src=" + dragon_ball[i] + ">";
    out += "</div></td>";
    if ((i + 1) % 4 === 0) {
      out += "</tr>";
    }
  }
  out += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("board").innerHTML = out;

  function hide() {
    var str;
    var x;
    for (x = 0; x < cover.length; x++) {
      str = "tile" + x;
      document.getElementById(str).innerHTML = "<img src=" + cover[x] + ">";
    }
  }

  // setTimeout based on the seconds chosen
  if (userInput === "3") {
    //Timer before it hides the card
    setTimeout(hide, 3000);
  } else if (userInput === "5") {
    setTimeout(hide, 5000);
  } else if (userInput === "8") {
    setTimeout(hide, 8000);
  }
}

//Shuffle the deck
function shuffle(a) {
  var j, x, i;
  for (i = a.length; i; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    x = a[i - 1];
    a[i - 1] = a[j];
    a[j] = x;
  }
}

function memory(tile, val) {
  if (dragonball_cell.length < 2) {
    dragonball_ret.push(tile.innerHTML);
    tile.innerHTML = "<img src=" + val + ">";
    if (dragonball_cell.length === 0) {
      dragonball_cell.push(val);
      dragonball_ids.push(tile.id);
    } else if (dragonball_cell.length === 1) {
      dragonball_cell.push(val);
      dragonball_ids.push(tile.id);
      if (dragonball_cell[0] === dragonball_cell[1]) {
        flipped += 2;
        dragonball_cell = [];
        dragonball_ids = [];
        dragonball_ret = [];
        if (flipped === dragon_ball.length) {
          alert("Congrats!!! You Win!!!");
          location.reload();
        }
      } else {
        function turnOver() {
          document.getElementById(dragonball_ids[0]).innerHTML =
            dragonball_ret[0];
          document.getElementById(dragonball_ids[1]).innerHTML =
            dragonball_ret[1];
          dragonball_cell = [];
          dragonball_ids = [];
          dragonball_ret = [];
        }

        setTimeout(turnOver, 700);
      }
    }
  }
}

startGame();

//Inner timer to count till lose
setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
var count = 0;

function myTimer() {
  count += 1;
  //Give them 2 minutes
  if (count === 120) {
    alert("LOSE!!! 2 Minutes has passed. Reloading game");
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

```css
#board {
  margin: auto;
  width: 65%;
}

.difficulty {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

html {
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px black solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Part C</h1>

<!-- Container for clock -->
<h1 id="clock"><time>Timer:00:00</time></h1>

<div class="difficulty">
  <h2>You have 2 minutes</h2>
  <h2>How many seconds:</h2>

  <form>
    <select id="options" title="values">
      <!-- <option selected disabled>How many seconds</option> -->
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <!-- A Button that loads the js file -->
  <button type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myclick()">
            Submit
            <div id="mylink"></div>
          </button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</div>

<div id="cou"></div>
<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: you can access style attributes cardelement`.style.visibility = "hidden";` or you could use jquery $("cardlement-selector")`.hide();`

Comment: where could i put the `.style.visiblity = "hidden"` in the code?

Comment: As you mentioned that after matching the cards you want to hide those cards, so simply put the above code where you check if the cards are matching.

Comment: `document.getElementById("tile").style.visibility = "hidden";` I tried this after checking if they are `===` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
function hideThatDiv() {
   document.getElementById("hideThis").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="hideThis">I will be hidden</div>
<input type="button" onclick="hideThatDiv()" value="Click me to hide it">
```

Alternatively you could use jQuery:

```js
function hideThatDiv() {
  $('#hideThis').hide()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hideThis">I will be hidden</div>
<input type="button" onclick="hideThatDiv()" value="Click me to hide it">
```

Comment: I get the idea but how can I add this into my code. That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @theMan23 What's the element you want to hide?

Comment: `document.getElementById("tile").style.visibility = "hidden";` I tried this after checking if they are `===` but no luck.